# I can put a few more things in the package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

this is my package:

```json
{
  "name": "any name :D",
  "version": "3.2.0",
  "nameVersion": "",
  "descriptionVersion": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.0"
  },
  "description": ":D",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

as you can see, there are two more keys, nameVersion & descriptionVersion.. I thought it would be nice to leave them with the version, which comes with it when I put `npm init`..
But a question came to me, is there a problem if I put something that is normally npm? like, even if no error, is it a bad practice? Or am I just traveling? well, i tested it and it works fine, but i'm still thoughtful about it..

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see any documentation for those two fields. Probably OK to leave them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably okay to have additional properties, although it would probably be good to have any additional properties grouped together under a single key. Many JS libraries also use additional properties for example ESLint uses `"eslintConfig"`, etc. in `package.json`: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-eslintignore-in-packagejson